# How can I change a file's extension using PHP?

Tags: php, file

How can I change a file's extension using PHP?

Ex: photo.jpg to photo.exe

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In modern operating systems, filenames very well might contain periods long before the file extension, for instance:

```
my.file.name.jpg
```

PHP provides a way to find the filename without the extension that takes this into account, then just add the new extension:

```
function replace_extension($filename, $new_extension) {
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    return $info['filename'] . '.' . $new_extension;
}
```

Comment: To me, this is the best answer because it's using a function in PHP for what it was designed for. It also does the computation in one single command, which means less C code in the guts of PHP.

Comment: I think this should keep the path information: 
return $info['dirname']."/".$info['filename'] . '.' . $new_extension;

Comment: Without the path it possibly break your application!

Answer (score 26):

```
substr_replace($file , 'png', strrpos($file , '.') +1)
```

Will change any extension to what you want. Replace png with what ever your desired extension would be.

Comment: Warning: it will mess up your filename if it doesn't find any extension.

Answer (score 19):

### Replace extension, keep path information

```
function replace_extension($filename, $new_extension) {
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    return ($info['dirname'] ? $info['dirname'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : '') 
        . $info['filename'] 
        . '.' 
        . $new_extension;
}
```

Comment: Best answer! Watch out, `DS` not fit in this situation

Comment: Oh my ... I am so used to Magento where they define `DS` = `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. Edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: May be it's not safe because it change not only extension. For example, on Windows it may be change one separator to another.

Comment: @Enyby: what do you mean? Do you have a non-working example name?

Comment: 'c:\\windows\\system32/drivers/etc/some.file..png' - change to 'jpg' give next result: 'c:\\windows\\system32/drivers/etc\\some.file..jpg' - separator before filename changed. It may be cause some side effects in some cases.

Comment: That is not a valid windows path you are passing. should all be backslashes - no forward slashes. Use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR when creating your path.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you're right. But the fact is that - php allows you to mix the two separator for Windows. For example, is_dir('c:\\windows\\system32/drivers/etc') return true. Therefore, I warn about possible side effects.

Answer (score 8):

You may use the [`rename(string $from, string $to, ?resource $context = null)`](http://www.php.net/rename) function.

Comment: What if you're using a variable as the file name?

Comment: The function takes strings, it doesn't matter if those strings are string literals or string variables.

Answer (score 7):

Once you have the filename in a string, first use regex to replace the extension with an extension of your choice. Here's a small function that'll do that:

```
function replace_extension($filename, $new_extension) {
    return preg_replace('/\..+$/', '.' . $new_extension, $filename);
}
```

Then use the [rename()](http://php.net/rename) function to rename the file with the new filename.

Comment: Actually this is a bad idea.  In modern operating systems, filenames may contain periods within the name, for instance when chaning the extension to ".tif",  "this.is.a.test.pdf" when used in this would strip it to "this.tif"

Instead, use:
$info = pathinfo($filename);
return $info['filename'] . "." . $new_extension;

Comment: `preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '.' . $extension, $file)` to match the last found `.` but will not work if file has no extension

Answer (score 4):

Just replace it with regexp:

```
$filename = preg_replace('"\.bmp$"', '.jpg', $filename);
```

You can also extend this code to remove other image extensions, not just bmp:

```
$filename = preg_replace('"\.(bmp|gif)$"', '.jpg', $filename);
```

Answer (score 3):

For regex fans,
modified version of Thanh Trung's 'preg_replace' solution that will always contain the new extension (so that if you write a file conversion program, you won't accidentally overwrite the source file with the result) would be:

```
preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '.', $file) . $extension
```

Comment: This is a clever solution. By using a regex to simply strip the extension and then using string concatenate to apply the new extension it works under more conditions then any of the other solutions provided.

Answer (score 2):

Better way:

```
substr($filename, 0, -strlen(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))).$new_extension
```

Changes made only on extension part. Leaves other info unchanged.

It's safe.

Comment: If the file doesn't have an extension it will replace the full filename.

Comment: @klodoma Yep. But question about change from one extension to another. So it expect some extension present.

Comment: I understand; it worth to specify that in the answer at least.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
$oldname = 'path/photo.jpg';
$newname = (dirname($oldname) ? dirname($oldname) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  : '') . basename($oldname, 'jpg') . 'exe';
```

Or for all extensions:

```
$newname = (dirname($oldname) ? dirname($oldname) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  : '') . basename($oldname, pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) . 'exe';
```

Finally use [rename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php):

```
rename($oldname, $newname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Many good answers have been suggested. I thought it would be helpful to evaluate and **compare their performance**. Here are the results:

- answer by Tony Maro (`pathinfo`) took 0.000031040740966797 seconds. Note: It has the drawback for not including full path.
- answer by Matt (`substr_replace`) took 0.000010013580322266 seconds.
- answer by Jeremy Ruten (`preg_replace`) took 0.00070095062255859 seconds.

Therefore, **I would suggest `substr_replace`, since it's simpler and faster than others.**

Just as a note, There is the following solution too which took 0.000014066696166992 seconds. Still couldn't beat `substr_replace`:

```
$parts = explode('.', $inpath);
$parts[count( $parts ) - 1] = 'exe';
$outpath = implode('.', $parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the `strrpos()` approach because it is very fast and straightforward — however, you must first check to ensure that the filename has any extension at all.  Here's a function that is extremely performant and will replace an existing extension *or add a new one if none exists*:

```
function replace_extension($filename, $extension) {
    if (($pos = strrpos($filename , '.')) !== false) {
        $filename = substr($filename, 0, $pos);
    }
    return $filename . '.' . $extension;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I needed this to change all images extensions withing a gallery to lowercase.  I ended up doing the following:

```
// Converts image file extensions to all lowercase
$currentdir = opendir($gallerydir);
while(false !== ($file = readdir($currentdir))) {
  if(strpos($file,'.JPG',1) || strpos($file,'.GIF',1) || strpos($file,'.PNG',1)) {
    $srcfile = "$gallerydir/$file";
    $filearray = explode(".",$file);
    $count = count($filearray);
    $pos = $count - 1;
    $filearray[$pos] = strtolower($filearray[$pos]);
    $file = implode(".",$filearray);
    $dstfile = "$gallerydir/$file";
    rename($srcfile,$dstfile);
  }
}
```

This worked for my purposes.