# How to Rename and Change Extension of Uploaded Image in PHP

Tags: php, php-5.5

Can you please let me know how I can rename and change extension an image file on loading to the server?

What I would to do is changing selected image extension to `.jpg` (from .png or .JPEG) and hard code the name like `new-image-1`

for now what I have is this which exactly upload the image file as original name and extension.

```
$sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
$targetPath = "../uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name']; 
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change a file's extension using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193794/how-can-i-change-a-files-extension-using-php)

Comment: if you don't want to use the original filename, then why are you telling php to use it with `$targetPath = ...`? "I put my groceries on the counter. why are there groceries on the counter? I wanted to put them on the floor".

Comment: Marc B, thanks for reply so how can I get access to original file then?

Comment: You can't change the file extension from .jpg to .png and expect it open properly without using an image processor to convert it. Can you use ImageMagick in your environment? http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$getName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$explodeName = explode(".", $getName); //splits by .(dot)
$extention = strtowlower(end($explodeName)); //gets last splited value and returns extention
```

use of `explode` and `end` can achieve your requirement

know more about [explode](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) and [end](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_end.asp)

**in remark with change image extention to `.jpg`**

```
if (preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i',$extention))
        $imageTmp=imagecreatefromjpeg($tempImagePath);
    else if (preg_match('/png/i',$extention))
        $imageTmp=imagecreatefrompng($tempImagePath);
    else if (preg_match('/gif/i',$extention))
        $imageTmp=imagecreatefromgif($tempImagePath);
    else if (preg_match('/bmp/i',$extention))
        $imageTmp=imagecreatefrombmp($tempImagePath);
```

you can use the above code convert any image to `jpg`, and directly give a random new name concatenate with `.jpg`

Comment: Thanks but here I am just getting the file extension! so how can I change it?

Comment: change to what extention?

Comment: huh! check my edited answer @Behseini, i saw your question, missed that extention thing, but you didn't try answering me, instead asked to read the post. great!!

Answer (score 0):

Detemine what file type it is by examining the extension.

open the file from the source location with the Image GD library functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

`$img = imagecreatefrompng($source);`

then save the image:

`imagejpeg($img, $target.'.jpg');`

see also:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

If you just want to replace the extension use something like:

`$target = str_replace('.jpg','.JPEG',$filename);`

You can just rename a png to jpg.  While you might be able to and the browsers may fix it but you shouldn't...