# Parse text/csv from server and download it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

How to download file with data which comes from server in `text/csv` format?

I'm using `fetch`. I have function like this

```
download(content, filename, contentType)
    {
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(content);
        a.target = '_blank';
        a.download = filename;
        a.click();
    }
```

Response comes like `object`.

Hope your help!

Comment: Where are you using `fetch`? You've created a a link to your CSV file that the user can download. The result would be downloaded by the browser, not your code.

Comment: I just sending data to server, server send me response `text/csv`

Answer (score 0):

bruteforce method: replace the filename extension with .csv and then send it to your client. You can achieve that with php.
[replace filename extension with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193794/how-can-i-change-a-files-extension-using-php)

good solution : if you want to convert a file to csv, you will need a rather powerful api. Maybe your best bet is to read the file yourself if you know what youre expecting, and generate the CSV.